Theorem 28.4 [Chain Rule] Ross Elementary Analysis
The following is a segment of Ross's proof of the chain rule.
$f$ is defined on some open interval $J$ containing $a$. $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and suppose $f(x) = f(a)$ for $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$. Then there is a sequence $(z_n)$ in $J /\{a\}$ such that $\lim_n z_n = a$ and $f(z_n) = f(a)$ for all $n$. Ross then states that
$$
f'(a) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(z_n) - f(a)}{z_n -a} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{0}{z_n - a} = 0
$$
Since $\lim (z_n -a) = 0$, I'm unsure how we can conclude that $\lim \frac{0}{z_n-a} = 0$. Could you help clarify why this is true? Thanks.

Becuase $\frac{0}{z_n-a}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}0=0$
